How to add a "meta" element to the HTML in a response from a Servlet?
In Jakarta Servlet 6.1, how does one add a meta element to the response from a servlet?
For example, in HTML5 we can specify a character encoding like this:
<meta charset="UTF-8">  

The meta elements go in the header.

IIRC, you need to add a header to your HttpResponse - something like resp.addHeader("charset", "UTF-8");

You can use html5 to render a servlets response. The meta character is recognized by the browsers to set the page encoding for text.

A servlet can be used to render HTML, so you could output that meta tag. Or you could add a Content-Type header. Like,
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

Or, writing the HTML directly like
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
// ...
os.println("<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");

